# Como llenar un jcombobox , al dar click en un jtable

Tags: java

Se desea que al dar clik  en la infórmacion  que esta en el jtable , se llene el formulario , funciona con todos menos con el  combobox[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? Una pregunta que solo expone el enunciado de lo que se debe hacer no es muy bien vista en el sitio, te sugiero que leas ¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?, considera usar el enlace editar y añadir tu intento de solución. – anythingg hace 37 minutos

Answer (score 0):

el método en cuestión del comboBox no tiene la funcion de añadir el componente a la lista. Para añadir items en el prueba el metodo `comboBox.addItem(stringAnadir);`.

Te muestro un ejemplo:

```
//comboBox
        JComboBox comboBoxEmployee = new JComboBox();
         //devuelve una lista
        ArrayList<String> listDept = sqlProcess.listEmployeeName();
         //añade todos los items de la lista
        for(String dep : listDept) {
            comboBoxEmployee.addItem(dep);
        }
```

No es su código pero al no entenderlo muy bien no he hecho un ejemplo a base de el.